# Suppress Java warning when running kotlinc

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

Every time I run *kotlinc* i get a warning:

`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.`

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA:
Run -> Edit Configuration -> Enable launch optimization (deselect) -> OK